# How do I determine the block size of an ext3 partition on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, ext3

How do I determine the block size of an ext3 partition on Linux?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'block size'
Block size:               1024
```

Replace /dev/sda1 with the partition you want to check.

Comment: FYI for non ext3 i get `tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdg`
`tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdg1`, but 
@mik answer works great `stat -fc % /dev/sdg` and `stat -fc % /dev/sdg1`

Answer (score 61):

Without `root`, without writing, and for any filesystem type, you can do:

```
stat -fc %s .
```

This will give block size of the filesystem mounted in current directory (or any other directory specified instead of the dot).

Comment: Don't forget the dot at the end of that command as `stat -f` is expecting is expecting a folder to give you stats about.

Comment: And to further narrow it down to what the OP asked for: `stat --printf='%s' -f .`

Comment: with newlinestat --printf='%s\n' -f .

Comment: @JaniUusitalo, @c4f4t0r: thanks for the hint, corrected the answer using `-c` which is simpler than `--printf='...\n'`

Answer (score 13):

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/md2
```

will output something with:

```
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
```

Answer (score 12):

In the case where you don't have the right to run `tune2fs` on a device (e.g. in a corporate environment) you can try writing a single byte to a file on the partition in question and check the disk usage:

```
echo 1 > test
du -h test
```

Answer (score 8):

On x86, a filesystem block is just about always 4KiB - the default size - and never larger than the size of a memory page (which is 4KiB).

Comment: This is the same on every platform, the largest block size is supported by ext2/3 is 4096 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I learned something today ;-) I originally thought the ext3 blocksize could be 8k on platforms that supported 8k memory pages.

Comment: Wikipedia says it can be 8k: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Size_limits

Comment: @dfrankow: if you have 8k memory pages, such as on Alpha hardware, yes. But you do not have those on x86 hardware and that is what I was talking about.

Answer (score 7):

To detect block size of required partition:

1. Detect partition name:

   ```
   $ df -h
   ```

   for example we have `/dev/sda1`
2. Detect block size for this partition:

   ```
   $ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
stat <<Filename>>
```

will also give file size in blocks

Comment: This is not what the OP asked

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep "Block size"
```

where /dev/sda1 is the device partition. You can get it from `lsblk`

Answer (score 0):

[@narthi mentions using `du -h` on a tiny file too](https://serverfault.com/a/651790/357116), but I'll add some more context and explanation:

##### How to find the cluster size of *any* filesystem, whether NTFS, Apple APFS, ext4, ext3, FAT, exFAT, etc.

Create a file with a single char in it, and run `du -h` on it to see how much disk space it takes up. This is your cluster size for your disk:

```bash
# Check cluster size by making and checking a 2-byte (1 char + null terminator I
# think) file. 
echo "1" > test.txt
# This is how many bytes this file actually *takes up* on this disk!
du -h test.txt

# Check file size. This is the number of bytes in the file itself.
ls -alh test.txt | awk '{print $5}'
```

Example run and output, tested on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 on an ext4 filesystem. You can see here that `test.txt` takes up **4 KiB** (4096 bytes) on the disk, since that is this disk's minimum cluster size, but its actual file size is only **2** bytes!

```bash
$ echo "1" > test.txt
$ du -h test.txt 
4.0K    test.txt

$ ls -alh test.txt | awk '{print $5}'
2
```

---

Another approach:

[As @Mayur mentions here](https://serverfault.com/a/709432/357116), you can also use `stat` to glean this information from our `test.txt` file, as shown here. The "Size" is 2 and the "IO Block" is 4096:

```bash
$ stat test.txt 
  File: test.txt
  Size: 2           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 27032142    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ gabriel)   Gid: ( 1000/ gabriel)
Access: 2023-05-21 15:37:31.300562109 -0700
Modify: 2023-05-21 15:48:49.136721796 -0700
Change: 2023-05-21 15:48:49.136721796 -0700
 Birth: -
```

### See also

1. If formatting a filesystem, such as exFAT, and if you have a choice on choosing the cluster size, I recommend 4 KiB, even for exFAT, which might otherwise default to something larger like 128 KiB, to keep disk usage low when you have a ton of small files. See my answer here: [Is it best to reformat the hard drive to exFAT using 512kb chunk, or smaller or bigger chunks?](https://superuser.com/a/1785239/425838)